# Extjs SetEditor - Query Builder

Tags: extjs

I am trying to add an editor to a cell, depending on the combo value selected in another cell.

consider there are 2 columns, with one column a combo editor applied. If I select index 1, the column 2 adds a date editor, else a string editor.

Basically I am building a Query Builder, so
 |  |  |

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give a specific answer without seeing some sample code, but the basic idea would be to have the "select" handler for column 1 call "setEditor()" on column 2 with the appropriate editor object.

For more details, take a look at the [API docs](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/docs/) - look up "ColumnModel"

Comment: Hi,

I have tried that - I am getting following error..

A.startEdit is not a function
GridEditor()()ext-all.js (line 153)
getViewWidth()()ext-base.js (line 9)
[Break on this error] Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel=Ext.extend(Ext....("editorgrid",Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel);

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a bug in 4.0 which cause an error when you use setEditor(), but no one support or rebut me...